# Python Try Except - When is Finally actually needed

Tags: python

Just a curiosity question about the python try clause.

Given:

```
try: some code
except: do this
else: do that
finally: always do
```

When will the finally clause do something that this will not?

```
try: some code
except: do this
else: do that
always do
```

Comment: You need `finally` if exceptions could be raised in both `except` and `else` blocks. It will be executed even if those exceptions are raised.

Comment: `finally` is also useful if you have some code that's executed at the end of both `except` and `else`, so you don't have to repeat it in both places.